# Rails / Rspec: .should_receive(method).with(parameter) where parameter is not known until tested method is called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a method that creates a new object and calls a service with that new object as a parameter, and returns the new object.    I want to test in rspec that the method calls the service with the created object, but I don't know the created object ahead of time.   Should I also stub the object creation?

```
def method_to_test
   obj = Thing.new
   SomeService.some_thing(obj)
end
```

I'd like to write:

```
SomeService.stub(:some_thing)
SomeService.should_receive(:some_thing).with(obj)
method_to_test
```

but I can't because I don't  know `obj` until `method_to_test` returns...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending whether or not it's important to check`obj` you can do:

```
SomeService.should_receive(:some_thing).with(an_instance_of(Thing))
method_to_test
```

or:

```
thing = double "thing"
Thing.should_receive(:new).and_return thing
SomeService.should_receive(:some_thing).with(thing)
method_to_test
```